# perform a fetch query on html popup

Tags: javascript, html, dynamics-crm-2011

I have created a html web resource that I am showing when a ribbon button is clicked. On this popup I have a drop down list that I want to populate with a list of records that I have obtained using a fetchXml query.

My problem is that I have tried a few different ways to execute the query but it always comes back with errors. I'm guessing that the popup wont have the same range of functions that the parent form will have and so I will need to do something different to execute the query.

Currently I have it so that I have loaded an external script containing the functions needed to perform the fetch, but the code cannot see the CRM function of _HtmlEncode, and therefore fails.

Is there any way that I can get the popup to see the CRM functions? Or is there an alternate way of doing this?

EDIT: Some sample code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:asp>
<head>
   <title>Re-Assign</title>
   <script type=text/javascript src="ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx"></script>

   <script type=text/javascript src="http://crm/DEVCRM/WebResources:ts_/scripts/fetch_global.js"></script>

   <script type=text/javascript>

   function OnLoad_GetAreasAndConsultants() {

       var fetchXml = '<fetch distinct="false" mapping="logical" output-format="xml-platform" version="1.0"><entity name="ts_solution_area"><attribute name="ts_solution_areaid"/><attribute name="ts_descriptor"/><attribute name="createdon"/> <order descending="false" attribute="ts_descriptor"/><filter type="and"><condition attribute="statecode" value="0" operator="eq"/></filter></entity></fetch>';
       var fetchedRecords = FetchRecordsToolKit.Fetch(fetchXml);

       if (fetchedRecords !== null) {

            var areaList = document.getElementById("ddl_solution_area")

            for (var i=0; i<fetchedRecords.length;i++) {

                var name = fetchedRecords[i].getValue("ts_descriptor");

                areaList.options[select.options.length] = new Option(name, i);
            }
        }
   }
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Care to paste some sample code?

Comment: I've added some code, the script i'm trying to call is the fetch_global script

Comment: Whats the error you are currently getting?

Comment: Its an error relating the fetch script that i'm linking to, the pop up can't see _HtmlEncode as a function, saying it doesn't exist. My guess is because the pop up isn't a CRM pop up, but a HTML pop up, and so cannot see the CRM functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built something specifically for executing fetch within an HTML web resource.

https://github.com/paul-way/JCL/blob/master/jcl.js

Here's an example of using it:

```
var processProjectInfo = function (data) {
    if (data.length > 0) {
        // Set Project Header Information
        $('#ProjectTitle').html(data[0].attributes.new_name.value);
        $('#CompanyName').html(data[0].attributes.new_accountid.name);
    }
};

var loadProjectInfo = function (guid) {
    var fetchXML = " " +
        "<fetch mapping='logical' count='10'>" +
        "  <entity name='new_project'>" +
        "    <all-attributes/>" +
        "    <filter>" +
        "      <condition attribute='new_projectid' operator='eq' value='" + guid + "' />" +
        "    </filter>" +
        "  </entity>" +
        "</fetch>";

    JCL.Fetch(fetchXML, processProjectInfo);
};
```